# Unusual gaps while using JSeperator - Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, layout-manager

I have been working on a Swing GUI and getting some unusual and unwanted gaps after adding `JSeperator`, Any idea how to remove them? Or any other option to how to achieve this nicely!

**Visual Description**

[image]

Gaps are apparent before `JLabel` "Speed" and after `JSlider`.

**Related Code**

```
control.setLayout(new BoxLayout(control, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

...another code omitted...

control.add(orientation); //JLabel
control.add(norm); //JRadioButton
control.add(back); //JRadioButton
control.add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.VERTICAL));
control.add(speedLabel); //JLabel
control.add(speed); //JSlider
control.add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.VERTICAL));
control.add(turnOutLabel); //JLabel
control.add(right); //JRadioButton
control.add(straight); //JRadioButton
control.add(left); //JRadioButton
```

---

What I want is to Have have everything centred and separated by JSeperator,

**Visual Description**

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried horizontal glue or implementing an empty border for your `JSeparator` instances?

Comment: @mrkhrts glue doesn't help, it's simple one more component with unbounded max ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just replace `new JSeparator(...)` with the following lines (you can put them in a method if you want):

```
JSeparator separator = new JSeparator(JSeparator.VERTICAL);
Dimension size = new Dimension(
    separator.getPreferredSize().width,
    separator.getMaximumSize().height);
separator.setMaximumSize(size);
```

As @kleopatra explained, JSeparator has unbounded maximum size (in both directions), so the trick here is to limit the max width to the preferred width, but still keep the max height unchanged (because the preferred height is `0`).

Comment: nonononono ... never setXXSize - that rule holds for ... well ALWAYS and EVERYBODY (even you and me <g>)

Comment: It actually worked, But now I shouldn't as you said O(no) no with Big O ;), I will try Howard's recommendation, I guess it should work!

Comment: @kleopatra damn! I thought you and me were immune and could do that ;-) Seriously though, I don't find it critical in the snippet above (as long as no hard-coded pixel size appears, it still looks acceptable to me).

Comment: @kleopatra, also this behavior of `JSeparator` looks buggy to me: for a vertical separator the max width should be constant (same as pref width), for a horizontal one, the max height should be constant (same as pref height).

Comment: @kleopatra would you find a JSeparator subclass that fixes maximum size more acceptable?

Comment: I see it as a matter of code hygiene - never (crossing fingers, of course :-) do something that is basically wrong. And agreed: the unbounded max width smells buggy - as does zero pref: if its most preferred state is to not show up, it wouldn't be added ...

Answer (score 4):

The reason BoxLayout is adding those gaps is that

- the width of your frame (panel) is greater than the total pref sizes of the children
- JSeparator and JSlider have an unbounded (practically, it's Short.Max) max width while all others have a content dependent max
- BoxLayout respects max sizes, so all excess gets distributed between those three

The reason FlowLayout doesn't show the separators at all,

- JSeparator has a pref height of 0
- FlowLayout gives every child its pref size

The easy way out is Howare's first suggestion: add the complete control to a panel with flowLayout. The more robust solution is to switch over to a more powerful LayoutManager :-)

(removed edit again, BorderLayout.south/north doesn't ;-)

Answer (score 1):

change BoxLayout to new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT). This should work. Unfortunately I do not have a real explanation why BoxLayout does not work for you.

Comment: If I use FlowLayout, Swing docent show JSeperator at all :(, Very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You may put your `control` into another panel with a `FlowLayout`.

**Update:** Unfortunately setting the `control` to flowlayout directly via

```
control.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
```

does not work, since the separator's preferred height is zero and the separators will disappear.

Comment: If I use FlowLayout, Swing docent show JSeperator at all :(, Very interesting.

Comment: @SkeetOverFlow You're right. Thus you can always put it into another container.