# Java separate components with lines

Tags: java, swing, components, line

I am learning some GUI stuff on Java and I think Im missing something here.
I have some components vertically listed using BoxLayout, such as some JButtons one above other. Now I want to separate them drawing a line between them. Do I have to use the Graphics library or is there some Swing way to separate the components with a line?

Going straight to the question: How to draw a line to separate components (such as JButtons) and which is the recommended way of doing it?

Thanks!

Comment: *"a line to separate components"*  DYM a [LineBorder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/LineBorder.html), or do you mean a line that joins between one component and the next, like a flowchart?

Comment: Its really the JSeparator as stated below, but is there a way to make LineBorder has full width but 1 or 2px height just as line?

Answer (score 10):

[`JSeparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSeparator.html), shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769722/gap-size-after-placing-jseparator-in-java-swing/6770653#6770653), is commonly used in this context. It works well with most layouts. Also, consider [*How to Use Borders*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html).

Addendum: The `JSeparator` UI delegate for a given Look & Feel, often modeled on [`BasicSeparatorUI`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicSeparatorUI.html), is particularly simple. It's `paint()` implementation draws a one pixel line in the foreground color and an adjacent one pixel line in the background color. The lines are as wide (or high) as the component's bounds, depending on orientation. The layout manager determines the spacing, so you'll want to review [*A Visual Guide to Layout Managers*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: Its exactly what Im looking for. Thanks! However, there is a BIG space between the separator and the other components. I suppose the layout is giving the same height to all components including the separator.

Comment: +1, for the JSeparator and for the Borders. We don't know what the layout is doing because we don't know what layout you are using. Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem. Then maybe we can offer more help.

Comment: just for the record: problem with borders is that - by definition - they are around containers, implying more than one container in a somehow compounded form. The disadvantage is loss of cross-container alignment of child components

Answer (score 3):

JSeparator returns weird sizing hints, the most problematic bit for a max respecting LayoutManager like BoxLayout is its unbounded max, see also a [recent discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515241/unusual-gaps-while-using-jseperator-java) (which was about vertical separators, same for horizontal, though)